# Instantiate Child base on Parent positon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject ABC, I will spawn another GameObject (placeholder) as its child and at its exact location.

```cs
public new GameObject gameObject; 
public GameObject placeholder;

void Start()
{
        Instantiate(placeholder, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), gameObject.transform);
}
```

The code should, spawn placeholder at (0,0,0) of ABC's location with no rotation. right?

But instead I get quite the opposite, ABC is at -30, -15, 0 while placeholder location are 30,15,0.

Am I doing something wrong? please kindly advise, thanks in advance.

Any concept that I get it wrong from the code?

Answer (score 1):

The position you pass to instantiate is a world position, so they place ur object at v3.zero, the position that u saw after instantiate is the value in relation to parent

Just instantitate using parent position instead of zero, this will be an zero in relation to parent

Comment: Or you can use the Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent) version.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Answer (score 0):

> The code should, spawn placeholder at (0,0,0) of ABC's location with no rotation. right?

It's wrong, according to the [document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

> If the position and rotation are specified, they are used as the object's position and rotation in world space.

So the placeholder will spawn at the world position (0,0,0), and unfortunatly there is no good way to achieve this, you can spawn the placeholder first, change it's parent next.

```
var ph = Instantiate(placeholder, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
ph.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform, worldPositionStays: false);
```

Another way is using the parent's world position and rotation.

```
var parent = gameObject.transform;
Instantiate(placeholder, parent.position, parent.rotation, parent);
```